# Return string and run it as code

Tags: php, return, eval

I'm trying to create an Autoloader class, so that I'll be able to load all modules automatically. But the problem is, I want to set a global from configuration file, and later, just call all of them by using:

```
Autoloader::GetGlobals();
```

So far, I have these 3 files:

**Configuration.php**

```
<?php
global $Configuration;
$Configuration['Globals'] = "Core Database Templates Directory Debugger";
?>
```

**Autoloader.Class.php**

```
<?php
require_once('Configuration.php');
private static $Globals = "";
private static $MakeGlobal = "global ";

public static function GetGlobals()
    {
        $ParsedGlobals = "";
        $Globals2String = explode(" ", Autoloader::$Globals);
        foreach($Globals2String as $Global)
            $Globals[] = "$".$Global;
        $DefinedGlobals = count($Globals);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $DefinedGlobals; $i++) 
        {
            $LastElement = $DefinedGlobals - 1;
            if($i != $LastElement)
                $ParsedGlobals .= $Globals[$i].", ";
            else
                $ParsedGlobals .= $Globals[$i].";";
        }
        return Autoloader::$MakeGlobal.$ParsedGlobals;
    }
?>
```

I'm getting the right output:

```
global Core, Database, Templates, Directory, Debugger;
```

The next thing is that I want to interpret this as PHP code and not as a string, and **I don't want to use `eval()`** (because I've read many articles that says that this is the last function to be used).

So the question is, is it possible to run this string from `return` as PHP code by simply calling it as `Autoloader::GetGlobals();`?

Comment: What do you mean exactly, "as php code"? A string is a type of php code, so are you looking to convert that to an array?

Comment: I think he wants to inject it into a script and have it be interpreted by php not as a variable but as keywords

Comment: So i want to run it in php exactly as global variables, but not a simple string

Comment: Those articles telling you that `eval` is the last function to be used are trying to tell you its a bad idea to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @developerwjk so how else than i can implement this idea?

Comment: You should rethink your architecture to get rid of global variables. Why do you need them?

Comment: Because im using many files, and sometimes just calling them to access certain function from classes, not all of them are static and i dont want to define them in each class again and again

Comment: @Ivan Zhivolupov, What I meant is the very idea is the problem. That's why the docs for `eval` (http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.eval.php) have this disclaimer that it "is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code." Anything else that does the same would be essentially the same, right?

Comment: @developerwjk Yes, but that i've no idea how to create kind of the same thing (i mean auto inclusion of globals)

Comment: You do know that any variables that have already been defined in the global scope are available in the `$GLOBALS` super global array right? If you really needed global access to the variables, you could just use that.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost as bad as using eval(), but there's variable variables, if you choose to go down this path of madness and chaos:

```
function foo($arg) {
   global $$arg; // note the $$
   echo "$arg / $$arg";
}

$a = 'bar';
foo('a');
```

output:

```
a / bar
```